# Concatenate Table Row Data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have 3 columns that I export as `csv`/`xcls` using `PHP`.

- root
- production conjugation
- sku = root . "-" . production conjugation

[image]

Here is the code that export those 3 columns

```
case 'root':
      return !empty($image->product->sku) ? $image->product->sku : '';

 case 'productconjugation':
      return !empty($image->{$field}) ? $image->{$field}->short_name : "";

case 'sku':

      if(!empty($image->{$field})){
          return $image->product->sku.'-'.$image->{$field}->short_name;
      }else{
        return $image->product->sku;
      }
```

---

## Result

It exported to production conjugation column, but for some reasons, when I tried to concatenate it in my sku column. It never did.

I couldn't really spot what I did wrong. Is this something that I did wrong in my switch case statement?

Comment: Seems that `$image->{$field}` is empty and therefore only `sku` is returned. Did you check the value of `$image->{$field}`?

Comment: @simon : But the there is some data ... as you can see it, it return and print out on the product conjugation column, and I'm not sure if you spot it, but I used the same condition on my if check. `!empty($image->{$field}) ?`

Comment: I know but I assumed that you have some kind of a loop around your switch statement and so I thought it might be that `$image->{$field}` changes during iteration. I don't see any other problems in this part of your code. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Add `Log::debug('$field = ' . $field)` in your third case statement and then check your log file for the result. I'm sure you'll find some unexpected values there.